# Discord.py True Key Permissions

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
  @commands.command()
  @commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.user)
  async def roleinfo(self,ctx,*,role:discord.Role):
      guild = ctx.guild
      perms = ", ".join(str(permission) for permission in role.permissions if true_false == 'true')
      embed = discord.Embed(description=f'''
>〉 **Role Created On:** {role.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}
>〉 **Roles ID:** {role.id}
>〉 **Roles Color:** {role.color}
>〉 **Mentionable:** {role.mentionable}
>〉 **Position:** {role.position}
>〉 **Hoist:** {role.hoist}
>〉 **Permissions:** {perms}
''', color=discord.Color.orange(),timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
      embed.set_author(name=f"{role.name}s Information", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
      embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}.", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
      await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

I am trying to make a roleinfo command that filters out the `true` Key Permissions of a role, but the response seems to be empty. I am having no errors.

[image]

Comment: what is `true_false`?? Where have you defined that?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `Role.permissions` returns a `Permissions` object, rather than a `List[Permission]` object. You can get each permission’s value by iterating through the role’s permissions.

```
for permission in iter(role.permissions):
    print(permission)
```

The following code will print tuples containing the info for each permission.

```
(str(permission), bool(value))
```

This can be applied to your code as so:

```
perms = ", ".join(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] else "", iter(role.permissions))))
```